# PHP opendir() not opening apache alias directory

Tags: php, apache, directory, alias, opendir

I've defined an Alias directory in Apache (2.4) to access and list some files that are outside of my document root, and it works perfect when opening an specific file, but i need to iterate throw the whole directory and function opendir is giving me the following error:

> Warning: opendir(http://192.168.0.165/archivosHCL/archivosOOSS): failed to open dir: not implemented in C:\Apache24\htdocs\clinica\verArchivos.php on line 41.

Indexes are enabled in the alias directory definition, so if i put "http://192.168.0.165/archivosHCL/archivosOOSS" on the browser, it shows the list of files correctly.

Here's my alias directory definition:

```
Alias /archivosHCL "C:/ARCHIVOS/HCL"
    <Directory "C:/ARCHIVOS/HCL">
      Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
      AllowOverride All
      Require all granted
    </Directory>
```

Comment: You're trying to use `opendir` on URL. It should only be used for local file directories

Comment: The problem is that browsers do not allow to open local files located outside the root. That's why i implemented alias.

Comment: The Apache alias is really only for the browser. `opendir` does not run as a web request, so has nothing to do with the browser. If the directory is readable/executable by the Apache user that is running `C:\Apache24\htdocs\clinica\verArchivos.php`, then it should be able to open `C:/ARCHIVOS/HCL`